# Kilz PVA primer cracks and peels

Tags: drywall, painting, primer

I have used Kilz PVA primer for the first time yesterday. After the wall dried, some areas flaked and peeled but most just looks like spider web cracks. Never experienced this issue before and Before anyone asks, yes; the walls were wiped and cleaned of Debris before I sprayed. I read other people having same issue, curious if anyone figured out why this happens. I tend to do some experiments, after my work is done. Just thought I would ask.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you use a fan to dry the wet paint? Is it very cold outside your house? If either, it dried too fast, which will cause or exacerbate the problem.

Comment: I think this could happen if the primer had been thinned too much or dried too fast.

Comment: What did you apply this product _to_?

Comment: Voting to close. Details are lacking and OP hasn't been back.

Answer (score 5):

Improper surface preparation.

Surfaces should be scuff-sanded to remove any gloss, that's to provide microscopic mountains so the new primer has something to adhere to.

Then surfaces have to be carefully cleaned of all contaminants, particularly oils, waxes and silicones.  Generally my rule of thumb is to wipedown the surface with the paint's solvent/diluent, but that doesn't do jack with water-based products.

In particular, water-based primers will be sensitive to the least oil contamination including skin oils.

Answer (score 2):

This product is supposed to be used over new drywall only. From the description, it's not clear whether OP used primer over previously painted or new drywall.

I see others suggested either incorrect preparation, or incorrect use (ie using over previously painted surface)

In my case, it was neither. PVA primer cracked in places where a new drywall was used. As well, I have vacuumed all walls, and dusted all corners using a brush, while vacuuming, so, that we can rule those suggested issues out.

In my case, I sprayed and backrolled the primer. BTW, backrolling is a must in my experience with this primer - mixes in scuffed paper, gets rid of bubbles/pinholes.

I noticed that mostly it cracked in corners. We sprayed walls first, hitting corners with ceiling, and then we overlapped corners when sprayed ceiling, and I suspect that there is something to do with previous primer still being not ready to receive another layer of the primer, and ended up too thick in places. For some reason, it looked grey in places where it cracked after coating corners for a second time, while the primer was still wet.

Some experienced painters seem to be agreeing with my theory, quotes are from https://www.painttalk.com/threads/primer-cracking-on-new-construction-ceiling.25815/

> Has nothing to do with the cold. The paint was just too heavy.

> Mil cracks we call them. Sometimes we get a little crazy with a gun with a big or blowed out tip. No biggie. just Samd it off a bit and recoat usually. If it's real bad, skim it with mud. You know you did it if you did, cause when you backrolled the material- well you could telll.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/159218)

Comment: It does raise the likely issue, which was the use of PVA over existing paint.

Comment: @isherwood interestingly enough, in a corridor, that had a very tight skim coat, so tight, that in places there is none, just previous paint, that was cleaned with TSP, sanded, and washed, and Kilz PVA in my case did just fine in there (I was worried though, because they do say it's for new drywall only)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this was improper preparation, I think this was improper usage.

Primer is used for two basic reasons

1. To cover the surface so the paint has something to adhere to (and, as an upshot, block anything underneath)
2. To "soak in" the wall so the paint stays on the surface

The vast majority of primer is for case #1. It's got more primer chemicals to better adhere to the surface. Those same parts of your primer are also what tends to do the other things a primer is used for (i.e. stain blocking). When a paint says (inaccurately) that it is "paint + primer", it usually means the paint has some primer in it so it can adhere better to what's underneath. If you ever wonder what the difference between the cheap paint and the expensive paint grades are, this is almost always it. Premium paints have more primer in them.

The second use case is far less common because, most of the time as a DIYer, you're painting over a layer of paint. But brand new drywall is a terrible surface to paint on. If you take any paint (even a premium one) and slap it on, you'll quickly find you need multiple coats to achieve a good finish. The reason is that drywall is a porous surface. That paint will be soaked up like a sponge into the surface layer. In other words, you'll be using your paint as a primer. Since paint costs more than primer (that tinting ecosystem costs money, plush you have other things to protect the surface, color, etc), that's an expensive proposition.

PVA primer is for **new drywall only**. It's the weakest primer you can get, but for a new wall you generally don't need anything else. It's there to soak in so your paint doesn't, and it's a lot cheaper than paint or normal primer for that reason. If the PVA primer is cracking, it either means

1. You got something on your brand new drywall that is preventing adhesion (some cleaners might do that)
2. You painted over existing paint

My bet is #2. I would do a good sanding to knock off the loose primer and then go buy a regular primer (Kilz 2, Cover Stain, etc).

Comment: "My bet is #2. I would do a good sanding to knock off the loose primer and then go buy a regular primer (Kilz 2, Cover Stain, etc)." 

That would look terrible. Knock off flaked primer, then skim coat/mud the area to make it even, and apply *thin* coat of the primer (you can use the same), and make sure you feather  primer edges, so that the spot blends in with the rest