# Fracturing paint on newly finished drywall

Tags: painting

A painter painted a freshly taped kitchen for us.

Two coats of Kilz drywall primer and two coats of Benjamin Moore paint.

That afternoon it started to crack and by the morning it looks like this

[image]

I believe that’s because they didn’t let all coats of paint dry before applying the next?

How can I fix? Hopefully I can just sand the paint off and repaint — and not have to remud?

Edit: related post with exact scenario [Kilz PVA primer cracks and peels](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/264506/kilz-pva-primer-cracks-and-peels)

Comment: An *allegedly professional painter?* You say "Get your incompetent behind back here and fix this!" Coats not drying might extend all the way down to the mud not being properly dried, since you say "fresh mud" and that's a major mistake.

Comment: And this is why people should use licensed, bonded, and insured contractors. It's one thing if your buddy messed up (who you paid in "adult beverages"), but it's an entirely different thing when a paid professional does this.

Answer (score 6):

This looks like one of two things to me:

- Paint applied over drywall that wasn't adequately dry.
- Paint applied over *dusty* drywall, such as after sanding and where no brushing or vacuuming was done, and maybe no sealer was used.

In either case it's something the painter should deal with. It's a fundamental failure of basic expectations. It'll require scraping, skimming with joint compound, priming and painting. You don't sand wall paint. Save that for auto body work.